# Sketchup - Is it possible to display the name of a Component dynamically in a Text tag?

Tags: sketchup

Sketchup - Is it possible to display the name of a Component dynamically in a Text tag?

I want the Text to change if I rename the Component, the way dimensions change when you change its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an observer to detect when the name change and then update the Text object. I think `DefinitionsObserver` with the `onComponentPropertiesChanged` event should work for that.
You need to find a way to keep track of which text element to update though.

Comment: Hmm... I see, I'd have to write my own Ruby scripts no?

Comment: Yes. I also assumed that was what you where trying to do since you posted the question on a site dedicated to programming.

Comment: True, I can write Ruby but I've never interfaced with the SketchUp API. Any books or courses on the subject?

Comment: @unmircea try http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/index & 'Automatic SketchUp' the author distributed a free PDF

Comment: Great! Search for it here https://duckduckgo.com/?q='Automatic+SketchUp'&t=osx and the first link http://rhin.crai.archi.fr/rld/pdf/Automatic_SketchUp.pdf Thank you!